# SpringBoot with Keycloak authenticate from query parameter as well as header

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I have a Springboot application working with Keycloak where Keycloak automatically authenticates the request based on the Authorization: Bearer <> header.  I have a case where I need to have a direct URL link without the ability to add headers and I'd like to encode the token as a query parameter in that case.

Can anyone suggest a good way to both use a Authentication header as well as a ?token=xxx mode for validation?

Here is my Spring security setup:

```
   @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider
                = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(
                new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakConfigResolver() {
            @Override
            public KeycloakDeployment resolve(HttpFacade.Request request) {
                KeycloakDeployment deployment = null;
                AdapterConfig adapterConfig = new AdapterConfig();
                adapterConfig.setAuthServerUrl(System.getProperty("keycloak.auth-server-url"));
                adapterConfig.setRealm(System.getProperty("keycloak.realm"));
                adapterConfig.setResource(System.getProperty("keycloak.resource"));
//                adapterConfig.setUseResourceRoleMappings(true);
                adapterConfig.setSslRequired("external");
                adapterConfig.setPublicClient(true);
                deployment = KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(adapterConfig);
                return deployment;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you: Do you want to authenticate a non-authenticated user via an access token? Or do you want Keycloak to pass access tokens back to your application after users have been authenticated?

Comment: It currently works with the following header: Authorization: Bearer <theToken>, but I need it to work with a GET link that can be used without setting the HTTP headers.  For example /service?token=<theToken>.  Basically use the token as an API key